# Flux interleaved with Interval

Tags: project, project-reactor, flux, reactive, reactor

In the following code some arbitrary user input in form of a Flux is modelled by ZonedDateTimes. Then I try to interleave this Flux with a Flux.interval. I expect to see ZonedDateTime messages come in side by side with Long values.

The observed behaviour is that Flux.interval is swalloed completely.

From the documentation ([Flux.mergeWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#mergeWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)):

> Note that merge is tailored to work with asynchronous sources or finite sources. When dealing with
>   an infinite source that doesn't already publish on a dedicated Scheduler, you must isolate that source
>   in its own Scheduler, as merge would otherwise attempt to drain it before subscribing to
>   another source.

I already experimented with Schedulers but with no success.

The Kotlin code looks like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
import org.junit.Test
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.test.StepVerifier
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

class Test {

    @Test
    fun simpleFluxTest() {

        StepVerifier.create(
                Flux
                        // Create some test messages, i.e. simulate user input
                        .fromArray(Array(10) { ZonedDateTime.now() })
                        .delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(1100))
                        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                        .repeat(4)
                        // The actual code
                        .cast(Any::class.java)
                        .mergeWith { Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(0), Duration.ofSeconds(1)) }
                        .doOnNext { LOGGER.info("$it, ts: ${System.nanoTime()}") }
                        .filter { any -> any is ZonedDateTime }
                        .cast(ZonedDateTime::class.java)
                        // Part of unit test
                        .take(Duration.ofSeconds(6))
        )
                .expectNextCount(50)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify()
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(Test::class.java)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found the solution by myself.

You have to use the static method `Flux.merge` instead of `mergeWith`. This is the only way to isolate the infinite `Flux.interval`. The Problem with `mergeWith` is that on subscription the Flux itself will be consumed and the closure supplied by `mergeWith` will never be called.

Comment: Well done on solving it - it'd be worth writing that as an answer and accepting it so it's clearer if others have the same issue.